# What is the "odbc" library that Pyodbc is failing to find?

Tags: macos, pyodbc, unixodbc

I've successfully installed unixODBC 2.3.4 on Mac OS X 10.12.6 (Sierra) but when I try to run `pip install pyodbc` I run into the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lodbc
```

I assume that what it's looking for is libodbc.la that got installed with unixODBC:

```
test -z "/usr/local/lib" || .././install-sh -c -d "/usr/local/lib"
/bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libodbc.la '/usr/local/lib'
```

Is this not what Pyodbc is looking for? How do I get it to find and use it successfully?

Answer (score 2):

I've downloaded a copy of the [Pyodbc source](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) (version 4.0.17) and figured this out by examining its `setup.py`. It is indeed looking for unixODBC:

```
# The latest versions of OS X no longer ship with iodbc.  Assume
# unixODBC for now.
settings['libraries'].append('odbc')
```

This causes `ld` to be called with `-lodbc` which looks for `/lib/usr/libodbc.dylib`. Unfortunately since El Capitan, normal installations go into `/lib/local/usr`.

What I did to fix this, then, is to add the following line in `setup.py` under the `sys.platform == 'darwin':` section:

```
# unixODBC make/install places libodbc.dylib in /usr/local/lib/ by default
# (also OS/X since El Capitan prevents /usr/lib from being accessed )
settings['library_dirs'] = [ '/usr/local/lib' ]
```

I can then install this with PIP from my local system like so:

```
$ sudo pip install /path/to/pyodbc-4.0.17/
```

I'll work on getting a patch made to Pyodbc but this gets me by in the meantime.